# Spring Boot tries to connect to a database not specified in application.properties

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Hello Spring Boot Community,

I have come accross a weird bug: I have the datasource's configuration in application.properties,
but the hibernate connect to another database, it ignores the "spring.datasource.url" property. Even more, we i comment the data source url in application.properties, the program still works and connects with the wrong database.

When I drop the wrong database it connects with, the program throws an error claiming the datasource with the name "my_db", which is not specified in "application.properties" does not exist ?

Anyone could help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, have you checked if you specify the database in a `@Configuration` class and there you pass the "my_db" name?

Comment: 1) Try to run mvn clean maybe there is an old application.properties in the target directory 2) make sure the applicatoin.properties is in src/main/resources

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments. In fact, I haven't configured any bean for datasource

Comment: I tried to run "mvn clean" but with n effect

Comment: can you search your whole project workspace for occurences of  "my_db"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally get the root cause:

In fact, I forgot that have already an **environment variable** in my system called "**SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL**" with the value "**jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my_db**"; and as spring boot prioritize "System Variables" over "application.properties", it considered the the datasource url from the that environment. That's it.